# How to make search each page with given two inputs of page in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program to search only one page as given below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = input("Enter Page Number: ")
jd = input("Enter File text name: ")
with open('E:/demo/' + jd + '.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(page1 + '\n')
    url = 'http://localhost:8888/'
    url_ok = url + page1
    r = requests.get(url_ok)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        if link.text[0:2] == 'GT':
            print(link.text)
            f.write(link.text + '\n')
```

I have a server at http://localhost:8888/ and it has many pages with numbers like :-
http://localhost:8888/1
http://localhost:8888/2
http://localhost:8888/3
http://localhost:8888/4
http://localhost:8888/5
..
...
http://localhost:8888/1000000

and So on many crores of pages.
This program only takes 1 page and searches the result and writes to the file.
I want to create a loop so that it can take two pages numbers as input for example page 5 and page 10 . So this searches all from page 5 page 6 page 7 page 8 page 9 and page 10 according to this program.

Comment: ``I want to create a loop`` - and what's stopping you? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes Instead I want to search between two pages. but how code it seems confusing. because as if now it only takes One Page as input. I want to input two pages like 5 to 10 . So it searches from 5 to 10.

Comment: You have tens of millions of pages ("crores")? Please don't use Indian words here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop like this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start, end = 5, 10
base_url = "http://localhost:8888/"

for page in range(start, end):
    with open("E:/demo/file{}.txt".format(page), 'a') as f:
        url = base_url + str(page)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        for link in soup.find_all("a"):
            if link.text[0:2] == 'GT':
                print(link.text)
                f.write(link.text + '\n')
```

Note that you can still change start and end page number.

Comment: Your code works now I understand start and end in range. I have again modified it and works success. Is there any way to view this code in web browser?

Comment: What do you mean by viewing this code in a web browser?

Comment: can we view the results in web browser ? Means the print.

Comment: Your code is writing the output to a txt files, you can view them where ever you want, but if you want to view it in a web browser, you should use .html extension instead of .txt just because you want to view them on a web browser.